# Magento2: Tier price higher than regular(product) price display label ?

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice

I want to display when Add Tier price higher then regular (product)price display as working lower Tier price.
If Is possible  ?
How Can Do it?

Comment: can u clear your question more

Comment: Magento2: Tier price lower than regular price working fine but when set  Tier price higher than regular price not display product view page working ..

Comment: Magento always use lower price to display

Comment: Thank you for response but is possible to display higher price to display?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: so can you please tell me how is possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84171/discussion-between-vishal-baraiya-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @VishalBaraiya can you share your soln.

Comment: Hello @VishalBaraiya did you get any solution? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rewrite below class for this

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php`

create `di.xml` in your module and write below code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Product\Type\Price" />
</config>
```

and in your `[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Product\Type\Price`

Override `_applyTierPrice` method change code to below

```
protected function _applyTierPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice)
{
    if ($qty === null) {
        return $finalPrice;
    }

    $tierPrice = $product->getTierPrice($qty);
    if (is_numeric($tierPrice)) {
        $finalPrice = $tierPrice; //change this line from orignal code
    }
    return $finalPrice;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans but still not display tier price like see screenshot http://prntscr.com/l3ikyi

Comment: Not working for me as well.

Comment: Anyone have a solution here ?

Comment: I am also struggling with this.